# Ubuntu doesn't detect Windows 7 partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Windows 7 machine. I have set aside another partition in my only hard drive (1TB). When I put in my CD, the installer does not detect my Windows 7 partition, as it should, and the only option given to me is to wipe everything, which I do not want. I ran the Boot Repair tool and this is the URL it spit out.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5621531/

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try [fixpart](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and found the solution here -

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604074&page=4&p=10022223#post10022223

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.